# How would I add a check constraint for making sure a date is not in the future

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqlplus, check-constraints

I can't find the syntax to prevent people from entering a date in the future. I have this but it wont work? I am only allowed to use Oracle's SQL*Plus.

```
CONSTRAINT dateofenrolment CHECK (dateofenrolment  <= sysdate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, that can't be done *directly*:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number   primary key,
  3     datum    date     constraint ch_future check (datum <= sysdate)
  4    );
   datum    date     constraint ch_future check (datum <= sysdate)
                                                          *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint


SQL>
```

Lucky you, there's a simple workaround: create additional *dummy* column which will hold `sysdate` as default value, and then use that column in `check` constraint. Not inline (as it can't be done):

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number   primary key,
  3     dummy    date     default sysdate,
  4     datum    date     constraint ch_future check (datum <= dummy)
  5    );
  )
  *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
```

but as an **outline constraint**:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number   primary key,
  3     dummy    date     default sysdate,
  4     datum    date,
  5     --
  6     constraint ch_future check (datum <= dummy)
  7    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Aha. Table created. Let's test it. First to check today's date:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
03.06.2020 19:51:41
```

Insert date value which is in the past:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('20.05.2020 13:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'));

1 row created.
```

Insert date value which is in the future:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('20.12.2020 23:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'));
insert into test (id, datum) values (1, to_date('20.12.2020 23:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_FUTURE) violated


SQL>
```

So, yes - it works, if you can live with additional column in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in Oracle with a check constraint.  The issue is that functions used in a check constraint must be deterministic.  That is, they must return the same value given the same arguments.  Clearly, `sysdate` does not meet this requirement, because its value change every time.

Oracle imposes this restriction because the `check` constraint is true not only when the data is inserted (or modified) in the table, but for all time.

You can do what you want using a trigger, however.  Just define an `insert` and `update` trigger to prevent bad values from going in.